# How should I POST and serialize and array of arrays with DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue POST-ing a JSON object that contains and array of arrays and deserializing it using Django Rest Framework.

The idea here is that there can be a dynamic number of players (`players: 2`) and a list of lists/array of arrays of weapons that the players have (`player_weapons [[], []]`).

```
//javascript on client
var post_data = {
    players: 2,
    player_weapons: [
        ["sword", "shield"],
        ["mace", "slingshot"],
    ]};

var results = jQuery.post( url, post_data );

#serializers.py
class GameSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    players = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1)
    player_weapons = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ListField(
            child=serializers.CharField(min_length=1, allow_blank=True),
        min_length=0, 
        required=False),
    min_length=0, 
    required=False
)
```

The `request.POST` I get is:

```
<QueryDict: {'runs': ['1000'], 'additional_players': ['2'],
'player_weapons': ['sword,shield', 'mace,slingshot']}>
```

What's really weird is that when I do `request.POST['player_weapons']` I get:

```
mace,slingshot
```

whereas I'm expecting/hoping to get:

```
[['sword', 'shield'], ['mace', 'slingshot']]
```

Any help on how I should be structuring the POST and handling it in DRF would be awesome.

Comment: Did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214837/django-rest-framework-how-serialize-list-of-list ?

Comment: I don't know about `jQuery`, or how your client is set up, but I'm guessing your problem stems from the request not having ContentType set to `application/json`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [RishiG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2715819/rishig) for the help here.

Problem was that I wasn't specifying the contentType in the request.  I slightly modified it to use jQuery's ajax request:

```
    var posting = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(post_data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(){
        }
    });
```